# Почему при сравнении текст равен нулю, 'text' == 0 возвращает истину?

Tags: php

Есть вот такое условие:

```
if ('text' == 0) {
```

На Laravel 5.8 оно истинно, я может чего не понимаю... Как это может быть?

Comment: Оно и без Ларавел истинно: [`var_dump('text' == 0); // bool(true)`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fe59c349832e0bd2360cd145a81adbffdbc70780)

Comment: При нестрогом сравнении строки с числом, строка преобразуется к числу по описанным в документации правилам. А так как 'text' - это не числовая строка, то она преобразуется к 0.

Comment: @Paul Wall Используйте if ('text' === 0) {

Comment: @rjhdby вы в этом уверены? Мне всегда казалось что как-раз таки число преобразуется в строку в этом случае. То есть `'text' == '0'`

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК нет. Приводится к числу. Подобный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/929341/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA/929350

Comment: @byVerng гребаный пхп. У меня прибавилось причин его ненавидеть. :-(

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК что не так? Всегда так было....

Comment: @Эдуард Ироды! Я такую простыню накатал, а вы вопрос закрыли! :D Пришлось в дубликат отвечать - не выбрасывать же...

Comment: @rjhdby соряньте :-D ))

Comment: Приведение строки к `(int)`, если строка не числовая, всегда выдает `int(0)` Приведение строки к `(bool)`, если она не пустая, всегда выдает `bool(true)` Просто иногда путают именно эти моменты, когда сравнивают строку с разными типами, потому что многие привыкли, что `0` это `false`, а `1` это `true`. Но забывают, что это разные типы переменных и строки к ним приводятся по разному.